# jQuery-form and Json problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

Good day guys, I'm using jQuery-form to submit a multipart form.

This is my PHP code:

```
foreach($addedData as $key => $value)
    $result[$key] = $value;

echo json_encode($result);
```

Javascript:

```
function showResponse(responseText){
   alert(responseText);
}
$('button').click(function(){
    $("form").ajaxForm({
        success: showResponse,
        clearForm: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
});
```

With this, the response was [object Object]. But when I removed these two lines:

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

The response became:

```
{"key1":"val1","key2":"va2","key3":"val3"}
```

My questions are: Do I really have to remove those two lines? And how can I get the values of the `responseText` using Json?

Comment: If you want a traversable object returned, `responseText` is not the best name for the argument. It's an object (jQuery automatically parses it), not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `dataType: 'json'` then your `success` callback function will be passed the object the JSON represents, rather than a JSON string. jQuery implicitly handles converting the responseText to the object for you, so you don't have to do `JSON.parse(responseText)` for yourself. If the response isn't valid JSON, the `success` callback won't be executed; even if the AJAX request returned successfully.

To get the values out, just use `responseText` like any other Javascript object; though you may want to give it a different name to make it clearer what it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

By having the `dataType:"json", ..` you are telling the request that you want the returned item to be an object (like `$.parseJSON(responseText);`). Without it you will be given plain text.

To print the object you will need something like this:

```
function showResponse(responseObj){
   $.each(responseObj,function(i,v) {
         alert(i+' = '+v);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the lines then you get `string` (`'{"key1":"val1","key2":"va2","key3":"val3"}'`) in JavaScript (because it use respone as file with `text/text` mime tipe), if you don't then you get `Object` (`{"key1":"val1","key2":"va2","key3":"val3"}`), so I think you should not remove them, if you want loop though this for example. By the way, when you alert an object JavaScript convert object to string (always `'[Object object]'`).

Answer (score 0):

No you don't, but the alert-box can't display the JSON-object. Try doing Console.log(responseText) instead, and inspecting the result in the developertools in your browser. [object Object] is a object literal

Answer (score 0):

don't remove the below code from your script  and add the below code you will get the alert correctly

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

var htmlstr;
for(var i in responsetext)
{
htmlstr += i +"="+responsetext[i]+"\n";
}
alert(htmlstr);
```